# Алгоритм поиска лучшего хода

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d, поиск-пути

Делаю аналог игры Trap the cat (https://trap-thecat.com) на Unity. Клетки представляют из себя тайлы (UnityEngine.Tilemaps.TileBase, Tile).

[image: Скриншот из оригинальной игры]

Хотел бы узнать как можно находить лучший ход для кота. Проблемой является то, что игрок ставит препятствия коту. Соответственно, ближайший путь должен выбираться с учётом заблокированных для перемещения на них клеток.

Понимаю, что это что-то из темы теории игр, но я не нашёл подходящих туториалов или статей конкретно для этого случая (или похожих случаев). Тут много клеток которые принесут победу, а не всего одна. Плюс движение идёт по 6 сторонам.

Буду рад если кто-то отправит подходящую статью, или книгу в которой можно найти нужную информацию. (Или просто поможет от себя)

Comment: Любой алгоритм нахождения кратчайшего маршрута, теория графов в помощь. Единственное, о чем могу предупредить, если алгоритм будет предсказуемым, даже если он будет самым умным, игра станет скучной. Вся прелесть котов в непредсказуемости, и движения должны быть направлены на то чтобы запутать игрока, иначе кот окажется глупым. Кратчайший путь конечно надо всегда иметь в виду, но реальная тактика бота может или даже должна отличаться от него.

Comment: @aepot, игрок каждый ход кота может добавлять препятствия. Кратчайший путь к краю для кота не всегда является выигрышным в ситуации когда препятствия добавляются. Получается поиск в дереве ходов вместо поиска в графе позиций.

Comment: Хорошо, поизучаю данные темы. Спасибо Вам за помощь!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я ради интереса поиграл в образец, и там кота поймать проще простого, оставляешь ему дырку, пока он к ней бежит, строишь вокру нее встены и в последний момент закрываешь, дальше дело техники. А в идеале кот должен определять такие ловушки, типа сколько ходов потребуется чтобы закрыть проход и отказыааться от маршрута к ловушке при плохом раскладе. При таком поведении его поймать будет намного сложнее.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977732/what-is-a-good-algorithm-to-trap-the-cat-in-the-game-circle-the-cat